# maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin show no coverage

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I am using the maven-surefire-plugin version 2.17 with maven.

I am using jacoco-maven-plugin to analyze my junit tests:

My jacoco plugin set up in my pom.xml looks like this:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>agent-for-ut</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                        <append>true</append>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>post-unit-test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dataFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</dataFile>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.reporting.outputDirectory}/jacoco-ut</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I have a class under src/main/java/something/excel that looks like this:

```
package something.excel;

public class VDHTCStyle
{
    public int doSomething() {
        int i=0;
        return i+7;
    }
}
```

My test class under src/test/java/something/excel looks like this:

```
package something.excel;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class VDHTCStyleStyleTest
{
    private VDHTCStyleStyle vDHTCStyleStyle;

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        vDHTCStyleStyle = new VDHTCStyleStyle();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldDoSomething() {
        int something = vDHTCStyleStyle.doSomething();
        assertEquals(something, 7);
    }

}
```

When I run this with

```
mvn clean install
```

I see this in the logs:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.17:test (default-test) @ xxxxx ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/xxxx/modules/xx/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running something.excel.VDHTCStyleTest
|classnames | 2.2.3 | A simple utility for conditionally joining classNames together|
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.062 sec - in something.excel.VDHTCStyleTest
```

Now if I look at the generated jacoco-ut report file, I see something like this:

```
GROUP,PACKAGE,CLASS,INSTRUCTION_MISSED,INSTRUCTION_COVERED,BRANCH_MISSED,BRANCH_COVERED,LINE_MISSED,LINE_COVERED,COMPLEXITY_MISSED,COMPLEXITY_COVERED,METHOD_MISSED,METHOD_COVERED
Module: xxx,something.excel,VDHTCStyleStyle,9,0,0,0,3,0,2,0,2,0
```

As I understand it, it thinks none of the lines, instructions, branches or methods were covered.

Why? Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be that maven-surefire-plugin behaves unpredictably when specified twice in a multi module project

My parent pom had it in the build section, and the child module pom also had it in the build section. Because of that, it seemed to be running the tests, but the coverage was always 0 in the child module.

The fix was to remove maven-surefire-plugin from the child module pom, and only have it in the build section of the parent pom.

Problem sovlved.

Comment: was this for a specific version of surefire? was it reported as a bug?

Comment: No I didnt report it as a bug, since I felt it was bad configuration done on my part (I had included it twice)