# Conflit between jacoco-maven-plugin and maven-surefire-plugin

Tags: java, maven, code-coverage, maven-surefire-plugin, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a problem using both `jacoco-maven-plugin` and `maven-surefire-plugin`: it seems that no  coverage analysis is done!!!

In order to give you more info, I was using `jacoco-maven-plugin` and it was working fine. However I noticed a performance issue while running my tests and I found a solution here: https://github.com/nats-io/nats-streaming-server/issues/698

I added the following section to my maven's pom.xml:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--
                    Option used to speedup NATS tests (cf. https://github.com/nats-io/nats-streaming-server/issues/698)
                -->
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My performance issue was solved but I realized that coverage analysis was not done anymore!!! *(of course, I tried to revert my change: this defect disappears)*

On [the following page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37595883/maven-surefire-plugin-jacoco-maven-plugin-show-no-coverage) I saw that this defect was already treated but the solution proposed (moving "maven-surefire-plugin from the child module pom, and only have it in the build section of the parent pom") does not work for me

I did additional tests. While my tests was running, I tried to check the commandline that was run by maven

here is was I obtained:

**when only having `jacoco-maven-plugin` specified:**

```sh
$ ps aux | grep 'urandom\|jacoco'
```

pmesmeur 1477900  0.0  0.5 9181248 132192 pts/25 Sl+  21:58   0:02 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -javaagent:/home/pmesmeur/.m2/repository/org/**jacoco**/org.**jacoco**.agent/0.8.5/org.**jacoco**.agent-0.8.5-runtime.jar=destfile=/media/cersei/ssd/data/home/pmesmeur/Devel/Misys/Projects/SFX/Sandboxes/test.coverage.while.removing.maven.surefire.plugin/RemoteLpConnector/clientlib/lpconnector_integration/target/**jacoco**.exec,append=true -jar /media/cersei/ssd/data/home/pmesmeur/Devel/Misys/Projects/SFX/Sandboxes/test.coverage.while.removing.maven.surefire.plugin/RemoteLpConnector/clientlib/lpconnector_integration/target/surefire/surefirebooter2551385423703193145.jar /media/cersei/ssd/data/home/pmesmeur/Devel/Misys/Projects/SFX/Sandboxes/test.coverage.while.removing.maven.surefire.plugin/RemoteLpConnector/clientlib/lpconnector_integration/target/surefire 2021-06-30T21-58-25_026-jvmRun1 surefire7433391136694530406tmp surefire_06093582606115842162tmp

**when both `jacoco-maven-plugin` and `maven-surefire-plugin` was specified:**

```sh
$ ps aux | grep 'urandom\|jacoco'
```

pmesmeur 1478702  0.0  0.0   2632   772 pts/25   S+   22:03   0:00 /bin/sh -c cd /media/cersei/ssd/data/home/pmesmeur/Devel/Misys/Projects/SFX/Sandboxes/test.coverage.while.removing.maven.surefire.plugin/RemoteLpConnector/clientlib/lpconnector_integration && /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./**urandom** -jar /media/cersei/ssd/data/home/pmesmeur/Devel/Misys/Projects/SFX/Sandboxes/test.coverage.while.removing.maven.surefire.plugin/RemoteLpConnector/clientlib/lpconnector_integration/target/surefire/surefirebooter4018295361004976187.jar /media/cersei/ssd/data/home/pmesmeur/Devel/Misys/Projects/SFX/Sandboxes/test.coverage.while.removing.maven.surefire.plugin/RemoteLpConnector/clientlib/lpconnector_integration/target/surefire 2021-06-30T22-03-23_413-jvmRun1 surefire4924791797502979280tmp surefire_07998612759554882058tmp

**I am now perfectly sure that jacoco is not launched when `maven-surefire-plugin` is enabled**

I would appreciate if someone could help me

best regards
Philippe

Answer (score 0):

I tried to provide the `argLine` via the maven commandline:

```
 -DargLine="-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"
```

but I had the same problem

**I found a solution to my problem** on the following page: https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/prepare-agent-mojo.html

1. define a `<property>`:

   ```
   <argLine>-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom</argLine>
   ```
2. define an empty `<configuration>` in the `maven-surefire-plugin`

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
           <!-- no argLine here -->
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```